# These calculations are correct ? About  $\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Was trying to calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln x dx=-\gamma$$ and I found this question:

I want to analyze $$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx$$

With $u=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow du = \displaystyle\frac{-1}{x^{2}} dx  $,  and $dv=e^{-x} \Rightarrow v=-e^{-x}$

Then

$$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx = \displaystyle\frac{1}{x}\cdot-e^{-x}-\int-e^{-x}\cdot\displaystyle\frac{-1}{x^{2}} dx = -\displaystyle\frac{e^{-x}}{x}-\int \displaystyle\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{2}} dx$$

Integrating from the same form gives:

$$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx = -\displaystyle\frac{e^{-x}}{x} + \displaystyle\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{2}} + 2\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{3}}dx$$

Are these calculations are correct?, and more is  valid say :

$$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n!\frac{e^{-x}}{x^{n+1}}\ ?$$

> $\bf{EDIT}$: This series  helps me to
>   calculate it ? :
>   $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}\ln xdx=-\gamma$$ I don't know  how to turn
>   this series in something harmonic. If
>   not, is this the way to calculate that this
>   integral converges to $-\gamma$, which
>   is the form ?

Thanks

Comment: You have just derived an asymptotic series for the exponential integral.

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{Ei}(x)=-\mathrm{PV}\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-u)}{u}\mathrm du=\gamma+\ln(x)+\int_0^x \frac{\exp(u)-1}{u}\mathrm du$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The series diverges, but converges to your integral asymptotically: If you add up the first $n$ terms the ratio of the error to the $n$th term goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity

Comment: Thanks, then i can to continue trying with $-\gamma$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\,\expo{-x}\,\dd x = \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
$$
We take the derivative respect $\mu$:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\ln\pars{x}\,\expo{-x}\,\dd x = \Gamma\,'\pars{\mu + 1}
=
\Psi\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}
$$
We take the limit $\mu \to 0^{+}$:
$$
\color{#0000ff}{\Large\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}\,\dd x}
=
\overbrace{\ \Psi\pars{1}\ }^{\ds{-\gamma}}
\quad
\overbrace{\ \Gamma\pars{1}\ }^{\ds{1}}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\Large -\,\gamma}
$$